# Package version is showing in "apt list" but not in "apt-cache policy"

Tags: debian, apt

Using Ubuntu Focal, I have added a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/
```

and run `apt-get update`.

I would like to use this repository to install R version 4.3.1. `apt list` shows the version is available:

```
root@51b8582cb4a0:/rcheology# apt list r-base-core
Listing... Done
r-base-core/focal-cran40 4.3.1-1.2004.0 amd64
r-base-core/focal 3.6.3-2 arm64
```

But `apt-cache policy` does not:

```
root@51b8582cb4a0:/rcheology# apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.3-2
  Version table:
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 Packages
```

And if I try to install version 4.3.1, the system doesn't find it:

```
root@51b8582cb4a0:/rcheology# apt install -y r-base-core/focal-cran40
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Release 'focal-cran40' for 'r-base-core' was not found

root@51b8582cb4a0:/rcheology# apt install -y r-base-core=4.3.1-1.2004.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.3.1-1.2004.0' for 'r-base-core' was not found
```

How can I get apt to recognise and download this version?